# How to bind JavaScript variables with PHP generated JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have two js variables here for google map geolocation:

```
<script>
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: "<?php echo $lat; ?>", lng: "<?php echo $lng; ?>"},
        zoom: "<?php echo $zoom; ?>"
    });
                
    var image = {
        url: "<?php echo $imgurl; ?>",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size("<?php echo $mapwidth; ?>","<?php echo $mapheight; ?>")
    };
</script>
```

And, I wanna set some markers and infowindows with an object generated from PHP/SQL database.

This is the original form of js:

```
<script>
    var marker_config = [
        {
            position: {lat: 34.775974, lng: 120.329628},
            map: map,
            title: 'Place A',
            label: 'A',
            icon: image
        },{
            position: {lat: 35.547591, lng: 115.467302},
            map: map,
            title:'Place B',
            label: 'B',
            icon: image
        },{
            position: {lat: 34.734375, lng: 117.408866},
            map: map,
            title:'Place C',
            label: 'C',
            icon: image
        }
    ];
</script>
```

This object requires both js variables above in key map and key icon.

My PHP array is written like this:

```
<?php 
    $markarr = [
        array(
            'position'=>array('lat'=>34.775974, 'lng'=>120.329628),
            'map'=>'map',
            'title'=>'Place A',
            'label'=>'A',
            'icon'=>'image'
        ),
        array(
            'position'=>array('lat'=>35.547591, 'lng'=>115.467302),
            'map'=>'map',
            'title'=>'Place B',
            'label'=>'B',
            'icon'=>'image'
        ),
        array(
            'position'=>array('lat'=>34.734375, 'lng'=>117.408866),
            'map'=>'map',
            'title'=>'Place C',
            'label'=>'C',
            'icon'=>'image'
        )
    ];
 ?>
```

And in js block:

```
<script>
    var marker_config = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($markarr); ?>);
</script>
```

It just wouldn't work. I think maybe it's the problem of calling variables as strings. So, I've tried to drop quotes off of 'map' and 'image'. This didn't work, either. Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var marker_config = <?php echo json_encode($markarr); ?>;
</script>
```